# jquery parsing attributes error

Tags: jquery, xml

So I have this JS code:

```
var messages = xml;
console.log( messages );
```

which returns this:

```
<messages test='foo'></messages>
```

How do I get "test", considering that the following does **not** work?

```
$(xml).find('messages').attr('test'); //returns undefined.
```

Thanks in advance.

Added jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yJy8L/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(xml).filter('messages').attr('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
var xml = "<messages test='foo'></messages>", messages = xml;
 $(messages).attr('test');
```